# Custom Microtik Configuration

Tags: routeros

In short, i'm trying to load a custom RSC configuration into a Microtik Router

However after loading it in on the restart with:

```
/system reset-configuration no-defaults=yes run-after-reset=flash/vpn-regional-example.1.0.rsc
```

I am no longer able to connect to the router, it just continuously says "Verifying and Connecting"

Is anyone able to see any issue in the following:

```
# jun/29/2017 22:39:38 by RouterOS 6.34.4
# software id = NNIT-8400
#
/interface bridge
add auto-mac=yes comment=defconf name=bridge
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether2 ] name=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] master-port=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether4 ] master-port=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] master-port=ether2-master
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=2ghz-b/g/n channel-width=20/40mhz-Ce \
country=australia disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=\
ap-bridge ssid=Example wireless-protocol=802.11
set [ find default-name=wlan2 ] band=5ghz-a/n/ac channel-width=20/40mhz-Ce \
country=australia disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=\
ap-bridge ssid=Example-5GHz wireless-protocol=802.11
/ip neighbor discovery
set ether1 discover=no
set bridge comment=defconf
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk mode=\
dynamic-keys supplicant-identity=MikroTik wpa-pre-shared-key=myPassword123 \
wpa2-pre-shared-key=myPassword123
#/ip hotspot profile
#set [ find default=yes ] html-directory=flash/hotspot
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.89.10-192.168.89.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp disabled=no interface=bridge name=defconf
/ppp profile
add name=ovpn use-encryption=yes
/interface ovpn-client
add certificate=vpn_key.pem_0 cipher=aes256 connect-to=vpn.example.org.au \
name=vpn.example.org.au password=\
PNqilt66P5RKoXbPpazq port=443 profile=ovpn user=vpn-regional-example
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether2-master
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=wlan1
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=wlan2
/ip address
add address=192.168.89.1/24 comment=defconf interface=ether2-master network=\
192.168.89.0
/ip dhcp-client
add comment=defconf dhcp-options=hostname,clientid disabled=no interface=\
ether1
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.89.0/24 comment=defconf gateway=192.168.89.1
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.89.1 name=router
/ip firewall filter
add chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
add chain=input comment="defconf: accept establieshed,related" \
connection-state=established,related
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add chain=input dst-port=22 log=yes log-prefix="remote-mgmt " protocol=tcp \
src-address=X.X.X.X
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop all from WAN" \
in-interface=ether1
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="defconf: fasttrack" \
connection-state=established,related
add chain=forward comment="defconf: accept established,related" \
connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" \
connection-state=invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment=\
"defconf:  drop all from WAN not DSTNATed" connection-nat-state=!dstnat \
connection-state=new in-interface=ether1
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat log=yes out-interface=vpn.example.org.au
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" \
out-interface=ether1
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Australia/Brisbane
/system identity
set name=vpn-regional-rockham
/system ntp client
set enabled=yes primary-ntp=X.X.X.X secondary-ntp=X.X.X.X
/system routerboard settings
set cpu-frequency=650MHz protected-routerboot=disabled
/tool mac-server
set [ find default=yes ] disabled=yes
add interface=bridge
/tool mac-server mac-winbox
set [ find default=yes ] disabled=yes
add interface=bridge
/tool sniffer
set filter-interface=vpn.example.org.au
```

It reboots with the correct SSID of `Example`

Answer (score 0):

If you have ethernet cable plugged into port1, after that import you must switch to port2 (or 3 4 5 but not 1 anymore).

In your place I would comment out

> /system routerboard settings set cpu-frequency=650MHz
>   protected-routerboot=disabled

if the board is not the same wich produced the export it can be an issue.

You didn't specified the board, the import file is expecting a dual radio board  (wlan1 2.4ghz & wlan2 5 ghz); if your board have no such specs the import will fail.